# Best Way to Handle Different DateTime Formats in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am taking in data from an Excel sheet, and the `DateTime` values varies with the following permutations:

```
(d/M/yyyy HHmm)   1/2/2020 2359
(dd/M/yyyy HHmm)  25/2/2020 2359
(d/MM/yyyy HHmm)  5/12/2020 2359
(dd/MM/yyyy HHmm) 24/12/2020 2359
```

For other scenarios where they swap day and months, I would just want to catch an exception on that.

I tried several methods, such as ParseExact variations but I am always getting issues with one or another.

Is there a generic solution that can handle the above situations?

Currently I am using the following:

```
public DateTime ParseDateAndTime(string dateValue, int? timeValue)
{
    var combinedDate = $"{dateValue} {(timeValue ?? 0) / 100}:{(timeValue ?? 0) % 100}";

    return DateTime.ParseExact(combinedDate, "d/M/yyyy H:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

P.S. Data is retrieved from Excel, and a have a format specified (dd/MM/yyyy HHmm). But users might key in single digit of day/month, and I would like to handle it. All other formats than the specified ones, I would like to catch as exceptions...

Comment: Do you have the date and time values as one whole or as two separate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works:

```
var dates = new[]
{
    "1/2/2020 2359",
    "25/2/2020 2359",
    "5/12/2020 2359",
    "24/12/2020 2359"
};

foreach (var date in dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ParseDateAndTime(date));
}
```

---

```
public DateTime ParseDateAndTime(string dateValue)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(dateValue, "d/M/yyyy HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have date as string, but your time value might be null. Therefore I would suggest seperation of you parsing in 2 steps date and time.
The other thing is I would return it as datetime object, so I can use it the way I want in stead for using ParseExact. This way if your time is null or has issue you will still have your date parsed.

You can also of course if date is not parsing, adding a condition and return a default date in stead, thorw exception or something else.

Just a basic example, some thing like this:

```
public DateTime ParseDateAndTime(string dateValue, int? timeValue)
{
    var time = $"{(timeValue ?? 0) / 100}:{(timeValue ?? 0) % 100}";
    var isTimeParsed = TimeSpan.TryParse(time, out var timeParsed);
    DateTime.TryParse(dateValue, out var dateParsed);
    if (isTimeParsed)
    {
        dateParsed = dateParsed.Add(timeParsed);
    }
    return dateParsed;
}
```

In case you need to throw exception you do something like:

```
var isDateParsed = DateTime.TryParse(dateValue, out var dateParsed);
if (!isDateParsed)
{
    throw new Exception("date is not parsable");
}
```

---

In case you need to present a flag, I would suggest creating own object and extend  the above method, some thing like:

```
public MyDateTimeObject ParseDateAndTime(string dateValue, int? timeValue)
{
    var result = new MyDateTimeObject();
    var time = $"{(timeValue ?? 0) / 100}:{(timeValue ?? 0) % 100}";
    var isTimeParsed = TimeSpan.TryParse(time, out var timeParsed);
    var isDateParsed = DateTime.TryParse(dateValue, out var dateParsed);
    if (!isDateParsed)
    {
        result.ParsingIssue = true;
        return result;
        //Or
        //throw new Exception("date is not parsable");
    }
    if (isTimeParsed)
    {
        result.ParsedDatetime = dateParsed.Add(timeParsed);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And your class

```
public class MyDateTimeObject
{
    public DateTime ParsedDatetime { get; set; }
    public bool ParsingIssue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If the input is e.g. `3/13/2020`, is it possible to flag out as incorrect format? As the format to insert to `CRM` is dd/mm/yyyy`, I would encounter format exception.

Comment: check the last update, instead of exception you can do some thing else. you could present your data model that include parsed datetime object and eventully the errors, if you need example I can improve my example

Comment: may I know if the `DateTime.TryParse("3/13/2020", out var dateParsed)` above will always be `true`?

Comment: when this method can not parse, isDateParsed  variable will be false

Comment: @gymcode how does it look like, can you use the solution?

Comment: Thanks, your method worked, but I have some issues validating as it still accepts `MM/dd/yyyy`. I have used Alex's method in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you don't know the specific format of each `DateTime` value when reading it from Excel, correct? How do you get the data? For example if you directly open the Excel file using Interop or something else you may try to read out the `CellFormat` of the specific cell. For sure this requires that the format of the `DateTime` is correctly set in the Excel file / Excel sheet.

Or do you get the DateValues as a plain List without the reference to the Excel file / Excel sheet? Then you can try to use `TryParseExact` using different date formats and see which matches as `TryParseExact` returns a boolean as result. Tricky can be a date like 12/12/2020 - the 12 is valid both for month and for day. Therefore, it is necessary to get the format somehow.

Comment: We do have a format specified, which is (dd/MM/yyyy HHmm). But users might key in single digit of day/month, and I would like to handle it...

Comment: I see - my fault. I thought or understood that dd and MM can mix up in their position. For example: dd/MM/yyyy - MM/dd/yyyy. Should it read better next time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a date from Excel, and the data is stored as Date in Excel, try get it as a DateTime object using `Range.Value`.

**If** `DateTime.ParseExact()` **works, please just use it.**

If it is stored as a string and the `DateTime.ParseExact()` function does not work, however, I will advise you to write a function yourself to analyze the string.

For example:

```cs
 public static DateTime getDate(string date)
        {

            string[] splitedDate = date.Split('/');

            int day;
            if (int.TryParse(splitedDate[0], out day)) ;
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            int month;
            if (int.TryParse(splitedDate[1], out month)) ;
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            int year;
            if (int.TryParse(splitedDate[2], out year)) ;
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException();
            }

            return new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }
```

There might be a better solution though.